# Information From Forum is Not Being Sent to Database

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have been working on this project for hours and need fresh eyes as to why the information from the forum is not being submitted into the database.

I have checked that the connection to the database was working. Whenever I try to submit an entry to the database, it shows that nothing goes wrong and goes to https://example.com/beta/index.php?post=success as it is supposed to but nothing except the `auto_incremented id number` shows up into the database.

My form page:

```
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

require('loginregister-master/includes/config.php');

if ($_SESSION['username'] !== admin ) {
    header("Location: https://www.example.com/beta");
}


//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: loginregister-master/login.php'); }

include('sec/HTTPS.php');

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Post Blog</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="likesdislike/post.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="title" class="form-control" name="title' placeholder="Title">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Content</label>
    <input type="content" class="form-control" name="content' placeholder="Content">
  </div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <label>Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="etad' placeholder="Date">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Author</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author' placeholder="author">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>URL</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="URL' placeholder="URL">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>





</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The bit that 'should' handle the submission the database:

```
<?php

include('connect.php');


$title =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['title']);
$content =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['content']);
$etad =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['etad']);
$author =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['author']);
$URL =  mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['URL']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, content, etad, author, URL) VALUES ('" . $title . "', '" . $content . "', '" . $etad . "', '" . $author . "', '" . $URL . "')";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);

header("Location: https://www.example.com/beta/index.php?post=success");


?>
```

And of course, the bit that handles the connection to the database:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name");
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 ?>
```

Comment: You are ***not*** checking for errors. Noor should you use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @Xorifelse How would I go about this? That would help a lot.

Comment: `mysqli_query` returns a boolean for a reason. And you should use prepared statements. Doing the latter will automatically fix your issue.

Comment: `if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}`

Check for the error.

Comment: @Ash, unfortunately that bit returns nothing as I'm assuming it is because the only thing that is being submitted is the auto incremented id. I could be very wrong though.

Comment: `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="URL' placeholder="URL">` Set your **html** format properly.

Comment: @Virb That worked.. I have no idea how I missed that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DevonStuper: Thats good. I have answered it in below. Just mark it as accepted and do upvote please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced `"` in name of html tags. Just do it with `""`.

```
<form action="likesdislike/post.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="title" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Title">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Content</label>
    <input type="content" class="form-control" name="content" placeholder="Content">
  </div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <label>Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="etad" placeholder="Date">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Author</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" placeholder="author">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>URL</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="URL" placeholder="URL">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```